# Artio Booking is not compatible with Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

errors in Artio Booking with Joomla 3.3.6

> Fatal error: Declaration of TableReservation::bind() must be
>   compatible with JTableInterface::bind($src, $ignore = Array) 
>   Fatal error: Declaration of TableSubject::store() must be compatible
>   with JTableInterface::store($updateNulls = false)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, After some internal plugin coding, I managed to fix this issue.

Replace your files with these in **administrator\components\com_booking\tables** 
**Note : Please take a backup before proceeding.**

[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2xnd2xb4gywjla/artio_booking2.zip?dl=1)

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you should change function parameter as there in the error -

You should edit your file(inside table folder of component) which has definition of `TableReservation` class and search for bind function and change

```
function bind()
```

to

```
function bind($src, $ignore = Array)
```

similarly search for `TableSubject` class and there change

```
function store()
```

to

```
function store($updateNulls = false)
```

You should also check on the component site if they provide update.There might be more errors once you fix this.